# Sequence defined by branches of Lambert W

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, lambert-w

I'm wondering if there is anything known about the asymptotic behavior of the sequence $a_n=W(n,1)$. Here, $W(n,x)$ represents the $n^{th}$ branch of the Lambert W function, where by definition $x = W(n,x) \exp(W(n,x))$ for all $n$. I've made a plot of the of the first few $n$. The plot shows $W(n,1)$  in the complex plane.

[image]

A plot of $a_n$.

Clearly the points lie along some nice curves - what I would ideally like is an expression for these curves, at least in the large $n$ limit. Does anybody know of such an expression, or a reference where such a thing is derived?

Comment: What do you get if you compare it with $2\pi \mathrm{i} n-\log(2\pi \mathrm{i} n)+\frac{\log(2\pi \mathrm{i} n)}{2\pi \mathrm{i} n}$?

Comment: Very close agreement! Could you please elaborate on how you determined this? Ultimately, I am looking for a similar such expression for $W(n,\alpha)$ for an arbitrary "seed" value $\alpha$, so it would be very helpful to see how you landed at such a good expression. Thank you!

Comment: I just took the first 3 terms of the known [asymptotic expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13.E10).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!